# Changing custom UINavigationBar attributes not working completely swift

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar, uinavigationitem

I'm changing the default navigation bar for a custom `navigationBar`, to set a custom localised title but I'm not able to change it's title color nor the back button as I normally do. Can you see what I'm doing wrong?
Many thanks as usual

```
navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: .default)
navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
navigationBar.backgroundColor = .clear
navigationBar.backItem?.leftBarButtonItem?.tintColor =  Theme.secondTintColor // not working
navigationItem.title = NSLocalizedString("Route Checkings VC Title", comment: "")
navigationItem.titleView?.tintColor = Theme.secondTintColor // not working
navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem?.tintColor = Theme.firstTintColor
navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem?.tintColor = Theme.secondTintColor // not working
```

Comment: You need to change `navigationBar.barTintColor` and `navigationBar.tintColor`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
    navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.white]
    navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.white
```

Comment: First of all welcome to to this great community. Second, thank you. I did try this before but I must have done some typo..it works now as expected.